# Mean distance from origin of a random point in unit square

Tags: probability, integration

A unit square has vertices (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) and (0,1).
A point P is chosen at random inside the square; P is (x,y).
What is the expected mean of the distance of P from the origin O?
I think I need double integrals, but I am struggling!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Start supposing X,Y are iid uniform in $(0;1)$. Now you can do a drawing of your problem...

[image]

...and realize which is the formula of your random segment...and then using the definition of

$$E[g(X,Y)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy$$

you should be able to complete the solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. Let $D=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$, you can compute:
$$\mathbf{E}[D]=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dxdy\approx0.765196$$

Answer (score 0):

One surprisingly fruitful resource for questions of this type

> *pick [some number of points] in [some geometric figure], uniformly at random; what is the [expectation/distribution/...] of the [distance / some
> other quantity]*

is Wolfram MathWorld, where such problems are named *X Y Picking* (picking *Y* from *X*). So let us see what they tell about [Square Point Picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePointPicking.html):

> The expected distance to a fixed vertex is given by
> $$\overline{d}_\text{vertex} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx \, dy = \frac{1}{3}\left[\sqrt{2}+\sinh^{-1} 1\right] $$

which indeed has the double integral mentioned in the other answers, and a closed form expression (which numerically evaluates to about $0.7651957$).

Other similar resources there include "Square Line Picking", "Cube Point Picking", "Circle Line Picking", "Line Point Picking", "Triangle Triangle Picking" (I'm not kidding!) and [many more](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/RandomPointPicking.html). Quite useful at times, since the multiple integrals can be unwieldy.

Comment: Thank you.  That is very helpful.